# cudaMemcpyToSymbol in pycuda

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I am using pycuda and i would like to know if there is an equivalent to the function `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`

I would like to copy a constant from the host to the device like below

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy 
from sys import path
from struct import *
from gpustruct import GPUStruct


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # list devices
    ndevices = cuda.Device.count()
    print '{} devices found'.format(ndevices)
    for i in xrange(ndevices):
        print '  ', cuda.Device(i).name()





    # compile device.cu
    mod = SourceModule('''
    __device__ __constant__ int CONSTd;
    struct Results
        {
         float *A; 
     float *B;
     float *C;
        };

    struct fin
        {
         float *N;
        };

__global__ void  test(Results *src,fin *dest){
    int i=blockIdx.x *blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    src->C[i]=src->A[i]+src->B[i]+dest->N[i]+CONSTd;

    }''',
            nvcc='/opt/cuda65/bin/nvcc',
           )

kern = mod.get_function("test")




CONSTANTE=5
src_gpu = GPUStruct([(numpy.int32,'*A', numpy.ones(10,dtype=numpy.int32)),(numpy.int32,'*B', numpy.ones(10,dtype=numpy.int32)),(numpy.int32,'*C', numpy.zeros(10,dtype=numpy.int32))])
test_gpu = GPUStruct([(numpy.int32,'*N', numpy.array(10*[5],dtype=numpy.int32))])

#something like this:
**cudaMemcpyToSymbol(CONSTd, &CONSTANTE, sizeof(int));**

src_gpu.copy_to_gpu() 
test_gpu.copy_to_gpu() 
kern(src_gpu.get_ptr(),test_gpu.get_ptr(),block=(10,1,1),grid=(1,1))
src_gpu.copy_from_gpu()

print(src_gpu)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyCUDA implementation directly follows the CUDA driver API, so you can use any driver API code you can find as a model, but there are two things required to make this work:

1. Use the module function `module.get_global()` to retrieve the device pointer to the symbol within the compiled source module
2. Use `driver.memcpy_htod` to copy values to that pointer. Note that the PyCUDA APIs require that objects support the Python buffer protocol. In practice this means you should be using `numpy.ndarray` or similar on the Python side.

This is effectively what `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` does under the hood.

Comment: hello @talonmies ,  
i've tried this  
`CONST = numpy.int32(20)`  
`CONSTd,_ = mod.get_global("CONSTd")`  
`cuda.memcpy_htod(CONSTd, CONST)`  
`kern = mod.get_function("test")`  

but i get this error   
`TypeError: 'numpy.int32' does not have the buffer interface`  
it's very strange because it works when i am using an array with dtype

Comment: Right. This is the same problem as in your other question with structures. PyCUDA *requires* that objects passed through to the CUDA APIs support the Python buffer protocol. The documentation mentions this explicitly. Your best choice is to use numpy ndarrays. Then it will work